# Angular -> NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'edit'

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

Why when I click the edit button (blue icon with a pencil) I get an error:

*Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'edit'*

My repo:
https://github.com/RobotHabanera/august2023

I want the 'SinglePromotionComponent' component to open after clicking on the icon.

[image]

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TableComponent,
  },
  { path: 'edit',
    component: SinglePromotionComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'delete',
    component: SinglePromotionComponent,
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    SinglePromotionModule,
    PromotionsGridModule,
    EditBtnModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule,
  ]
})
export class PromotionsGridRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: you don't lazy load the `routing module`, instead it should be the standard `module`. Also, if you are going to create multiple buttons, I suggest you handle them as components, and then, in one single module to expose those reusable buttons, is not a good idea to have a module per button, or any reusable component

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use relative route feature of Angular routing. Why beacuse in complex nested scenario it will save your day. So it's a good practice to use it.
Let see how we can use
In Table component

```
export class TableComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRouted) {}

  // call navigatetoEdit on click of edit icon
  navigatetoEdit() {
    this.router.navigate(["../edit", { relativeTo: this.route }])
  }
}
```

I hope it will help to save this problem and future problems when you will have more nested complex route.

Comment: while it is your suggestion, do you have any place where Angular documentation recommends such approach? OP's approach is the standard most common way; with @Andres2142 comment probably being the answer

Comment: It was just a suggestion and I also explained why I'm suggestion. Also there is no harm to use relative routes and believe me in case of more than one level nesting route it's hard to provide a path from parent to last child route.